# delphi firedac sqlite commit

Tags: sqlite, delphi, commit, firedac

When I made a commit, I naively believed that the physical file of the database would be updated (changing the modification date), but obviously it does not work like that.
The physical file of the database is modified when the database is closed !!!

i wrote a little test application with (delphi 10.2.3)
  *  FDConnection1: TFDConnection;     (all default setting) (cachedupdate is false)
   * FDQuery1: TFDQuery; (all default setting)

My SQLite database has just one table 
CREATE TABLE `t_stritems` ( `IdItels` INTEGER, `St01` VARCHAR (200), `St02` VARCHAR (200), `St03` VARCHAR (200), PRIMARY KEY(`IdItels`) )

My code is very simple

Connect the database :

```
  FDConnection1.Connected := false;
  FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=SQLite');
  FDConnection1.Params.ADD('Database=' + Edit1.text);
  FDConnection1.Connected := true;
```

Insert rows into the database

```
FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;
FDQuery1.close;
fdquery1.sql.clear;
fdquery1.sql.add('DELETE FROM t_stritems');

FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
fdquery1.ExecSQL;
FDConnection1.Commit;

fdquery1.sql.clear;
fdquery1.sql.add('SELECT * FROM t_stritems');
fdquery1.Open;
for i := 0 to 15 do
  begin
    for j:= 1 to 2000 do
      begin
        FDQuery1.append;
        FDQuery1.FieldByname('IdItels').asInteger := (i*2000) + j;
        FDQuery1.FieldByname('St01').asString := 'Text 01 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByname('IdItels').asString;
        FDQuery1.FieldByname('St02').asString := 'Text 02 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByname('IdItels').asString;
        FDQuery1.FieldByname('St03').asString := 'Text 03 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByname('IdItels').asString;
        FDQuery1.post;
      end;
//    FDConnection1.Commit;
  end;
end;
```

Test Process :
    Connect the database : (the t_stritems file of my database contains 32000 records; the size of the database file is 2338 ko)
    After the delete sql, I have in the directory of my database file a journal file (xxxx.db-journal). the database file size is 2338 ko
    after the first commit,  I have always in the directory of my database file the journal file (xxxx.db-journal). the database file size is 2338 ko (no physical update)
    The program then adds 32000 records
    The modification date of the file (.db) of the database will be modified only when I leave my application.  !!!
    the journal file (.db-log) will be deleted at the end of my application

Questions :
    How to make the commit save data to the database ?
    Is this normal ? 
    That the physical file of the database is modified only at the closing of the application (and at the same time of the connection) ?

Thank you in advance for your answer
Best regards
Romuald

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused on how to use databases in Delphi.

1) First of all you need to add try/finally in your code in order to catch any exceptions and prevent memory leaks.

2) Use connection.StartTransaction - connection.Commit paired.

3) Commit must be used at the end of your loop. When you finsih with updating your data, then you call Commit to perform all the updates you made on your fields.

Here is how I would re-write your code in order to implement my suggestions above:

```
  FDConnection1.Connected := false;
  FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=SQLite');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=' + 'Edit1.text');
  FDConnection1.Connected := true;
  FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;
  // your first transaction
  // just use ExceSQL directly to run your SQL query
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL('DELETE FROM t_stritems');
  try
    // start your transaction and use query.Open()
    FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
    FDQuery1.Open('SELECT * FROM t_stritems');
    for i := 0 to 15 do
      begin
        for j := 1 to 2000 do
          begin
            FDQuery1.FieldByName('IdItels').asInteger := (i * 2000) + j;
            FDQuery1.FieldByName('St01').AsString := 'Text 01 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByName('IdItels').AsString;
            FDQuery1.FieldByName('St02').AsString := 'Text 02 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByName('IdItels').AsString;
            FDQuery1.FieldByName('St03').AsString := 'Text 03 Number : ' + FDQuery1.FieldByName('IdItels').AsString;
            FDQuery1.Post();
          end;
        // Dont use Commit inside loop. You should call Commit after you loop logic
        // FDConnection1.Commit;
      end;
    FDConnection1.Commit;
  finally
    FDConnection1.Close();
    FDQuery1.Free();
    FDConnection1.Free();
  end;
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comment
You're right, the try finally is useful, but it is not the problem (in fact there is no connection to create and query)
it seemed to me that firedac was creating a transaction automatically.

Imagine that in my loop, I do a very long treatment, I call for example a function that will do a lot of stuff, in return for this function I insert in my table the result. and that all the all dataexecution of the process of the two loops take about ten hours.

Comment: In this case, I will commit in the loop and not at the end of all the processing.
Of course, I am sure that my treatment respects the integrity of all the data.

my main question was that when you commit, the physical size on the disk of the database as well as the modification date of the base does not change. These properties change only when you close the connection.
If you modify the loop to make 100000 or 150000 insert, you will see that when you close the connection, it will take a while to close and you will see the pointer sql. even if you did the commit before.

Comment: By the way, if you want to insert data you have to make an append or an insert before the post to avoid exception ;-). And it's true that after 20 years of delphi I still have a lot of things to learn.